# Send request to 127.0.0.1 via HTTP which is forwarded on via HTTPS

Tags: php, postgresql, ssl, wamp

I am using WampServer (Windows) and PHP pgsql, and apparently something wasn't compiled with SSL support, because I get this error:

```
Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: sslmode value "require" invalid when SSL support is not compiled
```

This got me thinking... I wonder if I can ask pg_connect() to look for 127.0.0.1 on port 12345 (or something like that) using HTTP, and then some middle service could be run on my local system that would pass that on to the server using SSL.

Does anyone know how to do that?

**NOTE**

I'm trying to connect to the **Heroku** PostgreSQL server (which uses an Amazon Web Service URL) and requires an SSL connection. I had better luck Googling ***"amazonws.com postgresql stunnel"*** for relevant bulletin board messages.

**UPDATE**

Here is the stunnel.conf file that I used:

```
;See: https://medium.com/what-i-learned-building/580fdd492119

cert = stunnel.pem
options = NO_SSLv2
options = SINGLE_ECDH_USE
options = SINGLE_DH_USE
socket = r:TCP_NODELAY=1
options = NO_SSLv3
ciphers = HIGH:!ADH:!AECDH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:!3DES:!SRP:!PSK:@STRENGTH

[heroku-postgres]
client=yes
accept = 127.0.0.1:YOUR-CHOSEN-PORT
connect = THE-HOST-GOES-HERE:PORT
protocol=pgsql
retry = yes
```

Reference: https://medium.com/what-i-learned-building/580fdd492119

Answer (score 1, accepted):

postgresql does neither use http nor https for its connection, but has its own protocol. But you could use something like stunnel to tunnel a normal tcp connection inside ssl, e.g. if your local pg_client library is not ssl-aware you could create an stunnel on localhost which then forwards the data via ssl to the remote postgresql server.

Comment: Good idea. I am going to give that a try. I am familiar with configuring this type of application, and the documentation on setting up a Windows service looks simple enough. I will post back here what I find out.